# How to show values in Highcharts tooltip other than x and y when data points are too high?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to plot a line chart using Highcharts but high number of points do not have some fields in it and so the tooltip is unable to show relevant data. I have also set `"turboThreshold": 1000000`

Data format

```
[{
    "name": "Tasks",
    "data": [{
        "title": "Jog Loaned",
        "start_time": "14 Dec 2014 7:51:31",
        "end_time": "14 Dec 2014 7:55:27",
        "x": 1418523927000,
        "y": 33.89,
        "start_time_epoch": 1418523691000
    }, {
        "title": "Prod - RepliINte SEMI Grace",
        "start_time": "14 Dec 2014 7:55:27",
        "end_time": "14 Dec 2014 8:0:44",
        "x": 1418524244000,
        "y": 31.39,
        "start_time_epoch": 1418523927000
    }],
    "turboThreshold": 1000000
}];
```

[Plunker link to the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/zAZ08lqYNjdiZnSnU0Fz?p=preview)

Comment: What do you mean by "when data points are too high"? Do you mean `point.y` is too high? How much is too high? It would be great if you could say something along these lines: When this value is greater than something, I want the tool tip to show "too high" or to show "-" or...

Comment: @RocoCTZ: I mean when I have large dataset for example more than 1000 [link to turbo threshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.turboThreshold), then I am facing this kind of issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is realted with fact that you have enabled dataGrouping in highstock, so points are grouped and extra parameters are skipped.